# A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

hai im new on c# actually i have an issue with my code which i couldnt find the error. I making a controller which i can see the details that user sumbit. When im debug it say that " Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations". i try to put await every each of line but doesnt working.

plus in my cases i dont use for each method

here is my code :-

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id, string currentFilter)
    {
        try
        {

            BizRepMaster bizRepmaster = _bizRepMasterService.Find(id);
            
            

            if (bizRepmaster.RepCountry != null)
                ViewBag.BizCountry = _countryMasterService.Find(bizRepmaster.RepCountry).tCountry;
            else
                ViewBag.BizCountry = "";

            
            if (bizRepmaster.RepState == null)
            {
                ViewBag.State = "";
            }
            else
            {
                if (bizRepmaster.RepState == "Oth")
                {
                    ViewBag.State = "Others";
                }

                else
                {
                    ViewBag.State = GetStateName(bizRepmaster.RepCountry, bizRepmaster.RepState);
                    
                }
            }
            if (bizRepmaster.MailState == null)
            {
                ViewBag.MailState = "";
            }
            else
            {
                if (bizRepmaster.RepState == "Oth")
                {
                    ViewBag.MailState = "Others";
                }

                else
                {
                    ViewBag.MailState = GetBizStateName(bizRepmaster.RepCountry, bizRepmaster.MailState);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.AMNationality = _countryMasterService.GetCountryMaster()
                        .Where(a => a.tISO == bizRepmaster.RepNationality).Single().tCountry;
            ViewBag.AMIdType = _idTypeService.GetIdTypes()
                        .Where(a => a.TypeID == bizRepmaster.RepIdType).Single().LabelName;

            
            if (bizRepmaster.DialCode != null)
            {
                ViewBag.DialCode = _unitOfWorkAsync.Repository<Country>().Find(bizRepmaster.DialCode).tDialCode;
            }
            if (bizRepmaster.NatureOfBusiness != null)
            {
                
            }
            ViewBag.AMResType = _unitOfWorkAsync.Repository<ResidencyType>().Find(bizRepmaster.RepResidencyType).LabelName;
            ViewBag.AMJobType = _unitOfWorkAsync.Repository<SenderJobType>().Find(bizRepmaster.RepJobType).LabelName;

            ViewBag.StateList = new SelectList(_stateService.GetStates(), "nId", "tStateDesc");
            if (bizRepmaster.IdType != null)
                ViewBag.IdTypeList = _idTypeService.Find(Convert.ToInt32(bizRepmaster.RepIdType)).LabelName; 

            ViewBag.CreatedUserName = _userProfileService.GetUserProfile().Where(a => a.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(bizRepmaster.CreatedBy)).Single().LoginId;
            if (bizRepmaster.ApprovedBy != null)
            {
                ViewBag.ApprovedUserName = _userProfileService.GetUserProfile().Where(a => a.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(bizRepmaster.ApprovedBy)).Single().LoginId;
            }

            if (bizRepmaster.LastUpdatedBy != null)
            {
                ViewBag.LastUpdatedName = _userProfileService.GetUserProfile().Where(a => a.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(bizRepmaster.LastUpdatedBy)).Single().LoginId;
            }
            if (bizRepmaster.LastApprovedBy != null)
            {

                ViewBag.LastApprovedName = _userProfileService.GetUserProfile().Where(a => a.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(bizRepmaster.LastApprovedBy)).Single().LoginId;
            }
            ViewBag.SenderId1 = bizRepmaster.SenderId;
            return View("_BizRepDetails", bizRepmaster);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return PartialView("_ErrorMessageView");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any `Async` method calls in this code. But there may be one somewhere in those service methods?

Comment: i try to put `async` on every single call on this code. but i get new error which is " no extension method GetAwaiter". Then decide to put my orginal code on my question. plus how do i wanna call `async`? im really sorry because i just new into c#

Comment: But could `GetStateName()`, `GetBizStateName()`, `GetCountryMaster()` ... etc which you haven't supplied, be starting an async method on the context without waiting for it? And where in your method is the exception thrown? Surely the error would be on the previous statement?

Comment: issue fix! i just add `await` at the `GetStateName()`. Thank you so much sir for your time and assits. @JeremyLakeman